What does the SD Association's formatter do differently from normal formatting utilities in Windows, macOS and Linux?
According to the SD Association, it is strongly recommended for SD Cards to be formatted using their own formatting utility.
I had largely ignored this until I was able to recover two SD Cards that otherwise seemed as if they had failed. One had hundreds of bad blocks that couldn't be read or written to, and the other had become incredibly slow. In both cases, using dd to write zeros to the device wasn't fruitful, nor was formatting them in Windows or Linux.
However, once trying the SD Association's formatting utility, the card with bad blocks no longer had any bad blocks (though showed up as about 1GB smaller than before), and the other SD card that was running at about 1/4th it's normal speed was back up to about 90% of it's advertised speed.
Clearly the utility is doing some sort of garbage collection, provisioning of spare blocks, and marking off bad blocks, but how is this done?
I understand that each SD card has it's own controller in the card, which manages the flash memory, and I understand that these controllers are running their own software/firmware that manage how data is read or written to the physical flash memory itself.
What I'm wondering about is what the SD Association's formatting utility does that's different from Windows/macOS/Linux, and to what extent. Clearly there is some command being sent that a normal format doesn't send, but I can't seem to find any details about this online, and instead of making assumptions or guessing based on experience, I'd like an actual technical explanation of what it's doing and what it's limitations are.
I want to understand the mechanism so I can better leverage it in the future on SD cards, and do things like preemptive maintenance on SD cards, by running them through the formatter utility in a controlled fashion instead of waiting for them to fail unexpectedly when a backup can no longer be made, or replacing them needlessly just as a preventative measure.
